# Como recarregar grid sem precisar verificar se ela existe JS JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

O sistema foi construído com modais e é possível que exista uma modal lá no 2º nível que precise atualizar duas grids abaixo(uma na tela principal e outra na modal no 1º nível), mas nem sempre essa modal é chamada do mesmo lugar então ao concluir a ação é possível que essas duas grids não existam abaixo dela, logo toda vez que vamos usar `grid.fnDraw()` no JS precisamos verificar antes se a grid em questão existe com o `if(typeof(grid) != "undefined"`.

Queria uma opção para não precisar mais verificar toda vez que eu for recarregar uma grid se ela existe.

Pensei em algo como criar um método assim:

```
function recarregarGrid(grid) {
   if (typeof (grid) != "undefined")
       grid.fnDraw();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existem casos em que nós recarregamos várias grids que podem não existir naquele momento:

```
//Concluíu uma ação e precisa atualizar os dados das grids abaixo da modal
if(typeof(gridItem) != "undefined")
  gridItem.fnDraw();
if(typeof(gridFornecedor) != "undefined")
  gridFornecedor.fnDraw();
if(typeof(gridLocalEntrega) != "undefined")
  gridLocalEntrega.fnDraw();
if(typeof(gridStackOverflow) != "undefined")
  gridStackOverflow.fnDraw();
```

Mas de qualquer maneira eu não posso passar uma variável undefined por parâmetro.
Então eu preciso de uma maneira para poder passar a grid como parâmetro mesmo estando como `"undefined"` ou uma melhor solução para não precisar mais usar toda vez esse `if` antes de recarregar a grid.

Comment: que tal colocar o `if` dentro da função `fnDraw`?

Comment: eu não tenho como usar o .fnDraw em uma variavel undefined e por causa disso estoura erro, então não adianta eu colocar dentro do fnDraw porque ele nem chega lá

Comment: `grid` estaria relacionado a um elemento do DOM?

Comment: A estrutura da grid está no HTML, mas a grid é montada no JS e carregada no HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se você estiver rodando a partir do browser, você pode usar o objeto global 'window' para ver se uma determinada variável global existe

```
function recarregarGrid(nome) {
    window[nome] && window[nome].fnDraw();
}

recarregarGrid('exemplo')
```

Note que, no exemplo acima, 'exemplo' é um string contendo o nome da variável.

Ou, se você não quiser poluir o escopo global, você pode usar uma única variável global, para representar todos os grids, mas nesse caso, você precisa se lembrar de sempre registrar cada grid quando ele for carregado pela primeira vez:

```
gridsExistentes = {};

function recarregarGrid(nome) {
    gridsExistentes[nome] && gridsExistentes[nome].fnDraw();
}

function registrarGrid(nome, grid) {
    gridsExistentes[nome] = grid;
}

recarregarGrid('exemplo')

// (...)

registrarGrid('exemplo', gridPreviamenteCarregado);
recarregarGrid('exemplo')
```

Comment: Acho que o primeiro exemplo é o melhor pro caso. Funciona perfeitamente, mas é meio estranho passar a uma string com o nome da grid...

Comment: o pessoal aqui da equipe também não curtiu muito passar o nome como string ): por mais que ainda seja melhor do que fazer um if toda vez antes de usar o fndraw. Vou pesquisar se existe alguma opção melhor ainda

Answer (score 3):

**Editado depois do comentário:**
Você pode inicializar `grids` no começo do script como um objeto global que vai reunir todos os grids que existem. Sempre que você definir um grid, crie uma propriedade dentro desse objeto pra guardar. Assim quando você chamar `recarregarGrids()` basta iterar sobre os grids existentes ali e chamar a função.

```js
// Guarda um objeto para todos os grids
var grids = grids || {};

// Define a função de forma genérica, que vai iterar sobre os grids
// adicionados ao objeto
recarregaGrids = function() {
  for( var grid in grids ) {
    if ( grids.hasOwnProperty(grid) ) {  
        console.log(grids[grid]); // apenas para testar o valor de cada grid
        // grids[grid].fnDraw();
    }
  }
}

// Quando estiver definindo as grids, guarde todas elas dentro do objeto master
grids.grid1 = 'gridStackOverflow';
grids.grid2 = 'gridPadrao';
//etc

recarregaGrids();
```

Comment: Eu ajustei ali, eu tenho vários casos em que eu preciso atualizar várias grids CASO elas existam. Então não vejo como poderia aplicar essa solução.

Comment: Tipo, não é que a grid foi inicializada sem valor, mas que ela nunca foi inicializada porque ela não existe ali

Comment: mas você vai recarregar todas juntas ou uma só de cada vez?

Comment: Todas que existirem ao mesmo tempo. Eu atualizei o post ali

Comment: editei com outro método.

Comment: Mas você esta verificando uma propriedade, creio que o que ele esta querendo é verificar se existe no dom.

Comment: Não dá pra saber pelo código que ele colocou. Estou partindo do princípio de que ele controla a criação dos grids, por isso eles tem nomes diferentes, inclusive.